# Pattern matching while mouse click using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am using this code with CSS value to emulate a mouse click

> document.querySelector('#REDAPPLE-0').click();

Now as the CSS value `#REDAPPLE-0` keeps on changing with every page refresh (like `#GREENGRAPES-0` etc) and only the part `-0` is constant everytime, then how do I use the pattern matching to achieve the desired results for the code above? Thank you in advance.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Will this code help? ```document.querySelector('.*-0').click()``` Please guide

Comment: Look carefully at the reference I gave and/or at the top answer to the question linked to in the closure notice. Look at the use of $ to pick the end string.